# Complex time-bound cache keys in Google Guava

Tags: java, caching, guava

Sorry for the poor title but I didn't know how else to phrase my use case.

I'm trying to use a Guava cache to load user profile objects keyed by their IDs. The catch is that the profiles may change over time, so I need to key the request by the date as well. Further, I'd only like to cache a single profile for a single user (instead of 7 different profiles for every day of the week for a single user).

Is there any way to replace existing cache entries with newly loaded ones only if the date changes, instead of adding a new cache entry for the new unique key?

For clarity:

A sample key would look like `<user id, date>`

If I have a cached entry that is keyed by `<123, "2013-02-13">`, and a request comes in for `<123, "2013-02-14">`, there should only be one entry in the cache for user 123 after loading the new profile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you should be doing is to have a `Cache<UserId, DateAndProfile>`, and then to check yourself if the `DateAndProfile` needs to be overwritten.  The Guava caching API isn't going to let you treat different keys as "sort of the same" in any fancy way.

Comment: Ah well ok, I can work with that. Thanks for your quick response (and apologies for my delayed one!).